# Retract your false comment but leave it there for reference

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, flags, original-poster

So a moment ago I left a comment on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100845/crash-when-using-nsnumberformatter-to-convert-nsstring-to-nsnumber#comment21245234_15100845) saying that `%i` stood for integer and `%d` stood for double... I was wrong, and this was pointed out to me fairly quickly, now I am torn, 

Do I delete the comment to stop false information from spread (because users may just read that comment and then go on their merry way retaining it) and then confuse users who later on read the conversation of comments and have no clue what anyone is talking about because the origin of conversation is missing...

-or-
Do I leave it up for reference with the risk of it spreading false-information?

---

I think the ability for the author of a comment to mark that comment as "false" may be a good feature, as for how it would work I have no clue and that is open to discussion:

•Maybe it puts a <s>strike through</s> on the comment that when moused over disappears with a message box popping up explaining that the author of the comment has retracted their statement but left it up for reference.

Answer (score 28):

**Just delete it.**

Comments are meant to be ephemeral.  If your deletion makes other comments obsolete, flag them as such and a mod can clean things up.  We don't need a permanent record of your brief confusion.